# How to improve sqlite write performance in C#

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite

I'm using sqlite to save log and meet write performance issue.

```
string log = "INSERT INTO Log VALUES ('2019-12-12 13:43:06','Error','Client','This is log message')"

public int WriteLog(string log)
{
    return ExecuteNoQuery(log);
}
public int ExecuteNoQuery(string command)
{
    int nResult = -1;
    try
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                dbCommand.CommandText = command;
                nResult = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output error message
    }
    return nResult;
}
```

Search in google, transaction could improve the write performance significantly, but unfortunately I don't know when a log message will come, I could not combine the log message. Is there any other way to improve my log write performance?

I tried to add a timer to my code and commit transaction automatically. But I don't think it's a good way to speed up log write performance.

```
public class DatabaseManager : IDisposable
{
    private static SQLiteTransaction transaction = null;
    private SQLiteConnection dbConnection = null;
    private static Timer transactionTimer;
    private long checkInterval = 500;

    private DatabaseManager(string connectionString)
    {
        dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
        dbConnection.Open();
        StartTransactionTimer();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(transaction != null)
        {
            transaction.Commit();
            transaction = null;
        }
        dbConnection.Close();
        dbConnection =  null;
    }

    private void StartTransactionTimer()
    {
        transactionTimer = new Timer();
        transactionTimer.Interval = checkInterval;
        transactionTimer.Elapsed += TransactionTimer_Elapsed;
        transactionTimer.AutoReset = false;
        transactionTimer.Start();
    }

    private void TransactionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartTransation();
        transactionTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void StartTransation()
    {
        try
        {
            if (dbConnection == null || dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (transaction != null)
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                transaction = null;
            }
            transaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LogError("Error occurs during commit transaction, error message: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public int ExecuteNoQuery(string command)
    {
        int nResult = -1;
        try
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                dbCommand.CommandText = command;
                nResult = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
            LogError("Error occurs during execute sql no result query, error message: ", e.Message);
        }
        return nResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't open the database every time you log a single message; open it once and re-use the connection over the life of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This started out as a comment, but it's evolving to an answer.

1. Get rid of the `GC.Collect();` code line.
   That's not your job to handle garbage collection - and you're probably degrading performance by using it.
2. No need to close the connection, you're disposing it in the next line anyway.
3. Why are you locking? Insert statements are usually thread safe - and this one doesn't seem to be an exception of that rule.
4. You are swallowing exceptions. That's a terrible habit.
5. Since you're only ever insert a single record, you don't need to return an int - you can simply return a bool (`true` for success, `false` for failure)

Comment: Wouldn't parameter binding also help?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon do you see anything that needs to be parameterized here?

Comment: Something along command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO log VALUES(?,?,?)" and then command.Parameters,Add( "2019-12-12 13:43:06") ...

Comment: Also it the date is Now() it could be replaced by DATETIME('NOW') which may also result in a (little) speedup

Comment: Thanks your comments, @ZoharPeled. I have modified the code, but don't think it  could solve my performance issue.

Comment: sections 1 and 3 should improve your code's performance, other sections are not performance related. BTW, Why are you using a database as a log? There are plenty of log providers out there that can be used - why not use one of them?

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use the entity framework to do the communications with the database?
For me is the easiest way. It's a Microsoft library so you can sure that the performance is very good.
I made some work with entity framework and sqlite db's and everything works very well.
Here an example of use:

```
var context = new MySqliteDatabase(new SQLiteConnection(@"DataSource=D:\\Mydb.db;cache=shared"));
var author = new Author {
    FirstName = "William",
    LastName = "Shakespeare",
    Books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book { Title = "Hamlet"},
        new Book { Title = "Othello" },
        new Book { Title = "MacBeth" }
    }
};
context.Add(author);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The type of `MySqliteDatabase` can be created automatically using database first approach or with Code First approach. You have a lot of information and examples on the internet.
Here the link to the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/